# Brightness buttons not working properly

Tags: 13.04, brightness

After upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 the brightness control buttons on my laptop(Lenovo E430) are not working properly - when I try to brighten the screen, nothing happens, but when I try to dim the screen, the screen immediately dims to the lowest possible setting. I am then not able to change the brightness back up with the brightness control buttons and have to open Brightness & Lock settings to set it back up, where it works...

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo E430 and I ran into the same issue. I posted on the UbuntuForums and a friendly user helped me out. [The original post is here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145241&p=12648279#post12648279)

These are the steps I followed:

1. sudo gedit /etc/default/grub (I know the link says gksu but it said not installed or something when I tried it, so I just used sudo)
2. Look for the line that says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" and change it to this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
3. sudo update-grub
4. restart

After that my brightness controls with the keys worked fine.

Note: Before (and after) I did this, I was still able to change the brightness via the slider found in "Brightness and Lock" within System Settings. It was how I worked around the lack of function keys doing their job until a user helped me with this solution.

Hope this helps!